# JDBC connection to MySQL using SSL

Tags: java, mysql, ssl, jdbc

I want to connect to a database from java program using SSL certificate. Database server and the server in which java program is running are both different.

Database server **host: sn-db-70** (database secured with **TLSv1.2**)

Java program (**1.8**) running in server (CentOs) **host: sn-ser-20**

I got the certificate from the server (**ca-cert.pem**). First i connected using **mysql** command and provided the certificate, it logged in and showing the cipher in status. That way i confirmed certificate is correct.

I added the certificate to trust store.

```
openssl x509 -noout -fingerprint -sha1 -inform pem -in <path-of-certificate>

// And to verify
keytool -keystore <path to cacerts> --list | grep <fingerprint>
Enter keystore password: ******
"finger print output"
```

I also tried adding the certificate in my local(mac) system

```
keytool -import -alias for-ssl-db -fil <path-to-cert> -keystore cacerts -storepass changeit
```

Then when running JDBC program (in both local and in server), it is throwing below exception

```
cause by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unsupported record version Unknown-0.0
```

It is a simple JDBC program trying to select records from single table. Below is the connection string

```
jdbc:mysql://sn-db-07:3306/persons?user=sanjay&password=123456&enabledTLSProtocols=TLSV1.2&sslMode=PREFERRED
```

I tried lot of other options like autoreconnect, useSSL, requireSSL etc. But nothing worked.

I also tried setting up the truststore path in program

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "<path-to-cacerts>");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "changeit");
```

I gave debug option **-Djavax.net,debug=all**, It didn't list the above certificate i added (Is it supposed to?)

I'm not sure what i'm missing, Can someone please point it out.

Comment: Where is your MySQL being hosted currently?

Comment: It is in a different server (host: sn-db-70)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'with SSL from a Linux server'? The MySQL server needs its own certificate. And what do the two servers have to do with each other?

Comment: I want to connect to database from a java program (hosted in linux server) using SSL certificate. Database server and linux server are both different serveres here. Any more info you looking for @user207421?

Comment: I'm still looking for an answer to my questions.

Comment: @user207421 I have updated the question. SSL from linux server means "Connect to a database from JDBC using SSL certificate (Both are hosted in different servers)". What do you mean by "MySQL server needs its own certificate"?
I'm able to connect to that database with the certificate i have through "mysql" command utility.